# Sybase SQL - Select Most recent record and line up with the values from previous record

Tags: group-by, sybase

I am trying the following query on data table listed below....Sybase does not allow row_number() function. Any suggestions would be very helpful:

```
select 
    a.item_number,
    a.item_rate,
    a.item_code,
    a.effective_dt,
    r_prev.effective_dt,
    r_prev.item_rate,
    r.item_code
  from A a LEFT OUTER join 
            (SELECT item_number, item_rate, item_code,effective_dt 
                FROM A
                ) a_prev
            ON a.item_number = a_prev.item_number
            AND a.rating_eff_dt < a_prev.rating_eff_dt
  order BY a.item_number, r.item_rate, r.item_code, a.effective_dt desc, a_prev.rating_eff_dt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Select Number(*),<column list>
from table
```

Thank You.